# ajax success returning undefined data object

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I am returning a view from my action method which is called by ajax call.
but in ajax success it is returning undefined object. What is the Problem?

```
$.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: url,
          success: function (data) {
              if (typeof (data) === 'undefined') {
                  alert("Error");
                  return;
              }else {
                  $('#content').html(data);
              }
          },
          error: function () {
              alert("Error");
              return;
          }
});
```

Backend code is here :-

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     return view(); //Index is a view containing only "hello world"
}
```

Comment: share the back end code in 'view'

Comment: public ActionResult Index()
   {
    return view(); //Index is a view containing only "hello world"
   }

Comment: Which type of data you are returning from backend code.What is content type

Comment: @PinkiBansal Edit your question and update the codes there.

Comment: I am using c#.net with asp.net mvc

Comment: @urbz it is a get request and i am not sending any parameter to action method.

Comment: I guess you get the alert with `error` but from which callback?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an Ajax call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: can you browse to the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you declare a same variable in your code somewhere named data and assigned it undefined or you assigned "data = undefined" in console window.

If you do this either close the browser tab or browser itself.
And try again it should work.

For more detail refer following links :-

http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html

and

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-hoisting-explained--net-15092

Answer (score 0):

I am also using asp.net mvc and jquery ajax request in my application as well also tried your ajax code which is perfectly right. Possible reason for your error could be in your return view() like it could not be find.

One most another thing is as you are using ajax request it will not show any error directly for that you have to inspect in your browser console. I hope you will find problem while you inspect in your browser.